How to resolve build errors in Next.js?

I have such an error after building in nextjs, I can't build the project for some reason, you can see the error I got below, what could be the reason, if you know, please help!!!

Y [AggregateError]
at Y.from (C:\Users\progr\OneDrive\Desktop\eastline.next\server\chunks\68.js:264:85273)
at y.<anonymous> (C:\Users\progr\OneDrive\Desktop\eastline.next\server\chunks\68.js:266:9557)
at y.emit (node:events:519:28)
at m.<computed> (C:\Users\progr\OneDrive\Desktop\eastline.next\server\chunks\68.js:47:212424)
at ClientRequest.emit (node:events:519:28)
AggregateError
at Y.from (C:\Users\progr\OneDrive\Desktop\eastline.next\server\chunks\68.js:264:85273)
at y.<anonymous> (C:\Users\progr\OneDrive\Desktop\eastline.next\server\chunks\68.js:266:9557)
at y.emit (node:events:519:28)
at m.<computed> (C:\Users\progr\OneDrive\Desktop\eastline.next\server\chunks\68.js:47:212424)
at ClientRequest.emit (node:events:519:28)
at emitErrorEvent (node:_http_client:108:11)
at Socket.socketErrorListener (node:_http_client:511:5)
at Socket.emit (node:events:519:28)
at emitErrorNT (node:internal/streams/destroy:169:8)
at emitErrorCloseNT (node:internal/streams/destroy:128:3)
at aB.request (C:\Users\progr\OneDrive\Desktop\eastline.next\server\chunks\68.js:266:21310)
at process.processTicksAndRejections (node:internal/process/task_queues:95:5)
at async e (C:\Users\progr\OneDrive\Desktop\eastline.next\server\chunks\44.js:1:13707)
at async S (C:\Users\progr\OneDrive\Desktop\eastline.next\server\chunks\44.js:1:13862)
Generating static pages (19/20)  [ ===]
Error occurred prerendering page "/". Read more: https://nextjs.org/docs/messages/prerender-error
✓ Generating static pages (20/20)
AggregateError
at Y.from (C:\Users\progr\OneDrive\Desktop\eastline.next\server\chunks\68.js:264:85273)
at y.<anonymous> (C:\Users\progr\OneDrive\Desktop\eastline.next\server\chunks\68.js:266:9557)
at y.emit (node:events:519:28)
at m.<computed> (C:\Users\progr\OneDrive\Desktop\eastline.next\server\chunks\68.js:47:212424)
at ClientRequest.emit (node:events:519:28)
at emitErrorEvent (node:_http_client:108:11)
at Socket.socketErrorListener (node:_http_clieyour textnt:511:5)
at Socket.emit (node:events:519:28)
at emitErrorNT (node:internal/streams/destroy:169:8)
at emitErrorCloseNT (node:internal/streams/destroy:128:3)your text
at aB.request (C:\Users\progr\OneDrive\Desktop\eastline.next\server\chunks\68.js:266:21310)
at process.processTicksAndRejections (node:internal/process/task_queues:95:5)
at async e (C:\Users\progr\OneDrive\Desktop\eastline.next\server\chunks\44.js:1:13707)
at async S (C:\Users\progr\OneDrive\Desktop\eastline.next\server\chunks\44.js:1:13862)

Export encountered errors on following paths:
/(root)/about-us/page: /about-us
/(root)/contacts/page: /contacts
/(root)/dashboard/page: /dashboard
/(root)/page: /
/(root)/services/page: /services
/_not-found/page: /_not-found

I tried a lot of things but I couldn't find any solution, I also used prism in my project, I thought it was started, but I didn't get this error when I deployed before.

Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.
